# Tivoli Workload Scheduler [TWS] Conditional Dependency - How to implement?

Tags: tivoli, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I am reaching to SME on the subject after trying to figure out the solution of below scenario.
I have a very specific requirement:

1)  Say I have a schedule called SCH1, having 3 jobs JOB1, JOB2 and JOB3 like:

```
Schedule S1
JOB1

JOB2
FOLLOWS JOB1

JOB3
FOLLOWS JOB2

END
```

2)  The JOB1 is calling a shell script.
3)  Now if JOB1 shell script returns a code 0 – it is successful and execute JOB2 and JOB3. 
4)  If shell script returns code is anything other than 0, Still the JOB1 should not abend; but all other job JOB2 and JOB3 should be skipped  (or completed without run); and schedule should be marked successful.

I got below link online, which suggest that this should be possible. But when I refer to syntax for Job/Schedule definition; I am not able to figure out that how it should be written.

In the job syntax, it looks like that below can do the trick, but not so sure.

```
 [rccondsucc "Success Condition"] 
   [recovery 
        {stop | continue | rerun}
        [after [workstation#]jobname] 
        [abendprompt “text”] ]
```

Conditional Dependency:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_9.1.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.1/zos/src_man/eqqr1conddepevalex.htm?lang=en

Job syntax:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_9.1.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.1/distr/src_ref/awsrgjobdefn.htm?lang=en

Schedule syntax:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_9.1.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.1/distr/src_ref/awsrgjsdefn.htm?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is not possible.

With RCCONDSUCC you can fine tune the status of a job (SUCC or ABEND) depending on it's return code. This just means you are not limited to RC = 0 = SUCC or RC > 0 = ABEND.

With RECOVERY you can specify which action should be taken only when the JOB is in ABEND.

Here you want to force a JOB to SUCC and specify a RECOVERY....

Answer (score 0):

To skip Job2 and Job3 with the help of Conditional dependencies Job1 must be in status "E".  But you can add a Job4 to application that only runs if Job1 aborted (also defined with CondDep). This job completes Job1 (or whole application). 
It works -  I demonstrated just this example on customer meeting :-)

It is also possible that Job1 completes and jobs Job2 and Job3 are skipped if these jobs have CondDep to Job1: Job1 must be in status "C"  AND Job1 must end with RC<>0.

Comment: Welcome. This answer is not very clear, perhaps you could provide some code to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Thanks Michael for the response. I have given the example of the schedule/job in the original post. kindly take that example and post the answer with proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Since 9.3 FP1 this can be implemented with built-in [conditional dependencies](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/distr/src_tsweb/General_Help/Intro_distr_cond_logic_c.htm)

Assuming you want JOB3 to wait if JOB2 abends, using conditional dependencies your scenario can be implemented like this
[image]

```
 SCHEDULE SCH1 
 :
 JOB1
  DOCOMMAND "myscript"
  STREAMLOGON twsuser
  SUCCOUTPUTCOND GO "RC=0"
  SUCCOUTPUTCOND NOGO "RC!=0"

 JOB2
  FOLLOWS JOB1 IF GO

 JOB3
  FOLLOWS JOB2
  FOLLOWS JOB1 IF GO
 END
```

JOB1 has 2 `SUCCOUTPUTCOND` defined: GO if RC=0 and NOGO if RC!=0.
Both are SUCCOUTPUTCOND, meaning that JOB1 will go in SUCC in both cases.

- If JOB1 ends with RC=0, the GO condition is true and the `FOLLOWS JOB1 IF GO` dependencies are satisfied, so JOB2 and JOB3 can be run (JOB3 will wait JOB2 since it has also a `FOLLOWS JOB2`)
- If JOB1 ends with a RC that is not 0, GO is false and NOGO is true. Since at least on SUCCOUTPUTCOND is true, JOB1 completes in SUCC, but the `FOLLOWS JOB1 IF GO` are not satisfied and JOB2 and JOB3 would be set to `SUPPR` status and will not run.